# Efeitos CSS para usar em imagens

Tags: css, css3

Alguém saberia me dizer alguns efeitos de CSS para arquivos de imagem em geral? Conheço alguns, contudo gostaria de saber se existem efeitos como inflar, sombra projetada entre outros somente usando CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melhor artigo que [este aqui](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) não conheço.

Um exemplo do funcionamento, retirado do próprio artigo, é este:

```css
img { display: block; width: 90%; }

img.filtro {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<p>Imagem normal</p>
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/redwood-ukulele-top.jpg" alt="ukulele">

<p>Imagem com filtro</p>
<img class="filtro" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/redwood-ukulele-top.jpg" alt="ukulele">
```